# Merge multiple Excel files in one Excel sheet without copying the formulas and duplicating data

Tags: excel, vba

I try to merge multiple Excel file in to one master sheet.
The code below works perfect because is not duplicating the merged data. My only issue is that is copying also the formulas from other file ... what I need is only the values.

I try to change some part of the code to

```
PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6EQY.png)

[Error 400 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6o7f.png)

Than I get an error (.

Code Used:

```
Sub sumit()

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

Dim NoOfFiles As Double
Dim counter As Integer
Dim r_counter As Integer
Dim s As String
Dim listfiles As Files
Dim newfile As Worksheet
Dim mainworkbook As Workbook
Dim combinedworksheet As Worksheet
Dim tempworkbook As Workbook
Dim rowcounter As Double
Dim rowpasted As Integer
Dim delHeaderRow As Integer
Dim Folderpath As Variant
Dim headerset As Variant
Dim Actualrowcount As Double
Dim x As Long
Dim Delete_Remove_Blank_Rows As String


Range("A:A").Clear
Range("B:B").Clear
Range("C:C").Clear

Folderpath = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("I7").Value
headerset = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("F4").Value
Delete_Remove_Blank_Rows = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("F3").Value

NoOfFiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files.Count
Dim Files_Count_No_Of_Rows_In_Sheets(1000) As Double 'declare the array of the size of no of files in the folder


Set listfiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files
counter = 0
r_counter = 1
rowcounter = 1
Actualrowcount = 0

For Each fls In listfiles
counter = counter + 1
Range("A" & counter).Value = fls.Name
Next
'MsgBox ("count of files in folder is  " & NoOfFiles)
Set mainworkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set combinedworksheet = mainworkbook.Sheets(2)
mainworkbook.Sheets(3).UsedRange.Clear
'MsgBox ("Sheet is clear for the data to be copied")
For i = 1 To NoOfFiles
mainworkbook.Sheets("Combine").Activate
'MsgBox ("Sheet 3 is Activated")
mainworkbook.Sheets("Combine").Range("A" & rowcounter).Select
Application.Workbooks.Open (Folderpath & "\" & Range("A" & i).Value)
Set tempworkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set newfile = ActiveSheet
rowpasted = rowcounter
'MsgBox ("pointer at " & rowpasted)
newfile.UsedRange.Copy
'MsgBox ("Data is copied")
mainworkbook.Sheets(3).Paste
'MsgBox ("Data is pasted successfully")
'MsgBox ("Blank rows has been deleted  " & Remove_Blank_Rows & " " & headerset)
If Delete_Remove_Blank_Rows = "Yes" Then
'If Remove_Blank_Rows = Yes Then
'MsgBox ("Blank rows has been deleted" & Delete_Remove_Blank_Rows)
For x = mainworkbook.Sheets("Combine").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row To 1 Step -1
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(mainworkbook.Sheets("Combine").Rows(x)) = 0 Then
mainworkbook.Sheets("Combine").Rows(x).Delete
'MsgBox ("Blank rows has been deleted" & Remove_Blank_Rows)
End If
Next
End If
rowcounter = mainworkbook.Sheets(3).UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
'MsgBox ("row counter is updated" & rowcounter)
rowpasted = rowcounter - rowpasted
'MsgBox ("No fo rows pasted" & rowpasted)
delHeaderRow = rowcounter - rowpasted
'MsgBox ("Which row to delete" & delHeaderRow)
'MsgBox ("Pointer at row beforw deletion" & rowpasted)
If headerset = "Yes" Or headerset = "YES" Or headerset = "yes" Then
If delHeaderRow <> 1 Then
mainworkbook.Sheets(3).Rows(delHeaderRow).EntireRow.Delete
rowcounter = rowcounter - 1
rowpasted = rowpasted - 1
Else
End If
Else
End If
'MsgBox ("Header deleted")
'MsgBox ("row counter is updated" & rowcounter)
combinedworksheet.UsedRange.ClearOutline
'combinedworksheet.
tempworkbook.Close
'MsgBox ("no of rows are abt to get pasted in sheet 1")

Files_Count_No_Of_Rows_In_Sheets(i) = rowpasted
Actualrowcount = Actualrowcount + rowpasted
Next i
mainworkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.ClearContents
For Each fls In listfiles
r_counter = r_counter + 1
mainworkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & r_counter).Value = fls.Name
mainworkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B" & r_counter).Value = Files_Count_No_Of_Rows_In_Sheets(r_counter - 1)
mainworkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & r_counter, "B" & r_counter).Borders.Value = 1

Next
mainworkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B" & r_counter + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
mainworkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B" & r_counter + 1).Value = Actualrowcount
mainworkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B" & r_counter + 1).Borders.Value = 1
mainworkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1", "B1").Interior.ColorIndex = 46
mainworkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1", "B1").Borders.Value = 1
mainworkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "Files List"
mainworkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1").Value = "No Of Rows"

MsgBox ("List of Files are Availabe in sheet 1..Total " & NoOfFiles & " Files Combiled")
End Sub
```

Comment: Whats the error you got? Also you should not use `ActiveWorkbook` rather use `Set mwb = ThisWorkbook` for the masterworkbook and for the one you open use `set twb = Workbooks.Open(...)`. And then you can use vars for the Worksheets too, like `set sht = mwb.Sheets(2)` instead of `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)`.

Comment: The Error is: `Run-time error '5'`     `Invalid procedure call or argument`   image added on top. Don't know if I should change various line or only the Paste one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the error image there is `mainworkbook.Sheets(3).Paste xlPasteValues` which is wrong and should be `mainworkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(rowcounter, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`.

Comment: I have tried `PasteSpecial` the got `Error 400` and the code is opening an complete new Book were is copying the data and still is not formatting the data to values only :(. Image attached.

Comment: @Yanky `PasteSpecial` method needs a range, not just a sheet. Check edited answer.